# Как нормально настроить смену картинок при наведении мыши?

Tags: java, javafx

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: сделал при наведении мышкой смену картинки на объекте. Т.е. сделал кнопку для сворачивания в трей. Но при смене картинок окно не открывается снова. Если убрать эту функцию то все ок. Как исправить подскажите пожалуйста...

На текущей картинке мы наводим мышь на кнопочку в гридпейне и картинка там меняется. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при открытии выходит вот это. Точней ничего не выходит. Если отключить смену картинок все ок. Через кнопки пробовал, взбесился решил через картинки. Подскажите какие правки внести?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package PLATFORM.SLAYDERS.C_GLOBAL.A_VISION.FUNCTION_MENU.A_LITTLE;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LITTLE_ACTION {

    public static Stage FIRST_STAGE;

    public LITTLE_ACTION(GridPane GRIDPANE) {
        GRIDPANE.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            /**if (FULL_SIZE == false) {
                    READY_OPERATOR = false;
                }*/}
            });

        GRIDPANE.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                /**if (FULL_SIZE == false) {
                    READY_OPERATOR = true;
                }*/}
            });
        /** ВОТ ТУТ ВСЯ ВЕСЕЛУХА И НАЧИНАЕТСЯ
        GRIDPANE.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent enter_but_1) {
                //System.out.println("Мышь наведена");
                GRIDPANE.getChildren().remove(IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE);
                IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE = new ImageView(new Image(LITTLE_ACTION.class.getResourceAsStream("/LITTLE_WHITE_PICK.png")));
                IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE.setFitHeight((STAGE.STAGE_HEIGHT/100)*4);
                IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE.setFitWidth((STAGE.STAGE_HEIGHT/100)*4);
                GridPane.setHalignment(IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE, HPos.RIGHT);
                GRIDPANE.add(IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE, 0, 0);

            }

        });
        GRIDPANE.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent exit_but_1) {
                //System.out.println("Мышь выведена");
                GRIDPANE.getChildren().remove(IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE);
                IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE = new ImageView(new Image(LITTLE_ACTION.class.getResourceAsStream("/LITTLE_WHITE.png")));
                IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE.setFitHeight((STAGE.STAGE_HEIGHT/100)*4);
                IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE.setFitWidth((STAGE.STAGE_HEIGHT/100)*4);
                GridPane.setHalignment(IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE, HPos.RIGHT);
                GRIDPANE.add(IMAGES_ADD.IMAGE_LITTLE, 0, 0);

            }
        });
        */
        GRIDPANE.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent pressed_but_1) {

                FIRST_STAGE.setIconified(true); 
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А что будет, если не пересоздавать `ImageView`, а заменять `Image` внутри него?

Comment: @AndreyM попробую. Отпишу как только сделаю.

Comment: @AndreyM Тоже самое. Эффекта не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во общем, не много поплакал. Решил сделать через CSS.

```
.button {
  -fx-background-image: url("LITTLE_WHITE.png");
  -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -fx-background-color: transparent; 
}
.button:hover {
  -fx-background-image: url("LITTLE_WHITE_PICK.png");
}
```

Теперь при наведении мыши на Button это выглядит как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]